# Decreasing and bounded product of Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, examples-counterexamples, lipschitz-functions

Suppose I have a decreasing Lipschitz function $f:[0, \infty)\to [0,\infty)$ and an increasing Lipschitz function $g:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty).$ If the product $f\cdot g$ is decreasing, does it imply that $f\cdot g$ is Lipschitz? Intuitively, it seems to me that multiplying by an increasing function can only make $f$ decrease less slowly, but I'm unable to formalize this.

I've tried proving something like
$$f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y) \leq K(f(x)-g(y))$$
for $x<y$ and some constant $K>0.$ But I have not yet been able to.

If it helps to be more specific: I'm particularly interested in the case where $g(x) = x+c$ for some constant $c>0$ and it is known that $f(x)\left[g(x)\right]^\alpha$ is also decreasing, for some $\alpha>4.$

I might of course also be wrong with my intuition, in that case I would also really appreciate a counterexample.

Comment: $|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(y)+f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(y)|\le (k_g\|f\|_\infty+k_f\|g\|)|x-y|$. If it doesn't hold it must be because the domains are infinite.

Comment: @Chrystomath Yes, I'm able to prove it on a compact domain, but I'm interested in the case with unbounded domain.

Comment: If you consider $f$ and $g$ given by $g(x) = e^x$ and $f(x) = 1$, the resulting function $f\cdot g = g$ is not Lipschitz, only locally Lipschitz. If you mean strictly decreasing, then you might take $f(x) = e^{-x/2}$

Comment: @MushuNrek I'm interested in the case where the product $f\cdot g$ is also decreasing (not necessarily strictly).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Since g is locally Lipschitz, the only problems is at infinity, no? (If we want to accept problems at zero, we need to exclude it from the domain.) The problem at infinity should disappear for the product, because it is decreasing (and hence possesses a monotone limit. I hope I am reading it right this time.

Comment: @Mushu Thanks! Indeed, it must possess a limit. How might this imply that the product is Lipschitz?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f\cdot g$ is supposed to be decreasing, there is not a lot that could happen (monotone bounded continuous functions are very nice). Intuitively, the only thing that could go wrong is to have at some $x$ a situation similar to $-\sqrt{x}$ around $0$, i.e. an vertical tangent. And that would be very weird... (I know, that is not the most valid mathematical argument.)

More formally, we know that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable almost everywhere, same for $f\cdot g$. Furthermore, $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$ almost everywhere, and $fg$ is Lipschitz if and only if $(fg)'$ has finite $L^\infty$-norm. Now, since $fg$ is decreasing, we would need to have $(fg)'$ to go to $-\infty$. This is not possible towards $+\infty$, because $fg \geq 0$. Then, suppose that $(fg)'$ is unbounded (towards $-\infty$!) around some fixed $x\in [0,+\infty)$. Since $g' \geq 0$ (and hence $fg' \geq 0$), that means necessarily that $f'g$ is unbounded (towards $-\infty$) around $x$. At the same time, $f'$ and $g$ are bounded around $x$, because $g$ is continuous and $f'$ is Lipschitz.

If I am not mistaken, that should give the result.

Comment: I can see that this gives local Lipschitz, because it shows that $(fg)'$ is bounded around any $x$, but this is not sufficient to give global essential boundedness right? And to show that $fg$ is Lipschitz, we need that the derivative is a.e. bounded, rather than only locally (otherwise we only get that it's locally Lipschitz)

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the reply, I hadn't tried to formalize a proof using derivatives yet. Do you have a source for the claim that a function is Lipschitz iff its derivative is essentially bounded? I've only see the claim that any Lipschitz function has essentially bounded derivative, but not the other way around.

Comment: For the first point: if a function on $[o,+\infty)$ is locally Lipschitz, the only problem is towards infinity, and this possibility has been ruled out at the very beginning. You might consider the following intuition: if a function on a metric compact space is locally Lipschitz, then it is Lipschitz. Now, we compactify the interval by adding $+\infty$ to it. The monotonicity gives that is locally Lipschitz around infinity and so we got a locally Lipschitz function on a compact space. Now, this is not entirely true, because the extended positive real line is not a metric space anymore...

Comment: For the second point, you will need a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus, sometimes called Lebesgue's differentiation theorem. A function is differentiable almost everywhere and is the integral of its derivative iff it is absolutely continuous. This is the case if the derivative is locally integrable. Now, if it is essentially bounded, then you see that the properties of the integral give us Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: How does the monotonicity give us local Lipschitz around infinity? That would indeed complete the proof, but I don't see why this must be the case.

Comment: Only if we use also that the function is bounded from below. Write $h:=fg$. Suppose that $h'$ goes to $-\infty$ around $+\infty$. Then, by the integral representation, $h$ also goes to $-\infty$, contradicting the boundedness. That is why monotonicity is nice. There are less things that can go weong.